# Flash support for Xbox 360 joystick

Tags: flash, adobe, xbox360, xbox

Is it possible to use an Xbox 360 controller with the latest Flash player? If so, where can I find sample source code?

If a third party utility is required, I'd rather use something free.

I'm also interested in using the controller with a browser - is this possible?